# Postgres - will a larger database always be slower?

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

I have two structurally identical postgres database on different windows servers. One for development, and one live.

Records are inserted via a powershell script, the script uses stopwatch objects to record the duration of each INSERT.

In the early days of the project records in the development database would be processed at a rate of about 1 every 0.6 milliseconds, and in the live version at a rate of 1 every 1.4 milliseconds. I put the difference in timings down to the hardware - the live server is a few years old, the development one a lot newer.

After 12 months I've noticed that whist the INSERT speed on the development server remains the same, on the live server it's now over 10 times slower. (18ms per record).

The only difference between the two databases is the size. The development database drops all data after a month, the live version keeps the data forever. All the data is partitioned by month (both databases), at the start of every month a new partition is created for the new months data, on the development server last months partition will be dropped, on the live it won't be.

The data is only manipulated (inserted, updated or deleted) in the first 24 hours. After that it's only used for reporting.

Does the fact that the live database is large mean it has to be slow to? 90% of the live database is in tables that basically just sit there and don't do anything - so I have always assumed they wouldn't effect performance.

If this is the case, then what else might be effecting performance?

The following may be relevant (or not?)

- Servers are physcialy seperate and not even on the same network.
- Both servers are (should be) 100% identical in terms of schema, partitions, tablespaces, indexes etc...
- Both servers are running postgres v10, and the same version of windows.
- both servers have the same virus scanner and firewall
- The performance described is when both servers have only one connection (the powershell script doing the inserting)
- Both servers are still working correctly, there's no sign of any errors, the data appears to be all correct and there's no sign of any issues with locks (I've tried the queries listed [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring))
- I've not (knowingly) made any changes to one database that haven't been reflected in the other.
- Data is being accumulated at a rate of about 10-20 million records a day, the live database is now a few terabytes.
- There's plenty of free disk space on both servers.

I've only recently noticed the performance change, so I'm not sure if it's been slowly getting worse as the database grows, or if it's come on all of a sudden recently.

Is this performance degradation normal as the database grows - or should I be searching for some other cause? (if so what)

Thanks

Comment: More than likely it's your server and database settings which aren't set correctly. I'd look at how to set up PostgreSQL and understand its settings, as well as your windows server before saying that PostgreSQL is the issue. By the way, there are very large companies using PostgreSQL and terabytes is nothing to what they have.

Answer (score 0):

ok - solved it.

when the databases were built I accepted all the default values for most settings - this includes how often tables get vacuumed. For reasons I still don't fully understand two months ago Postgres simply stopped vacuuming one of the tables on the live database.